# how does "getChild" works in twisted

Tags: python, twisted.web

The twisted web documentation says that getChild has to be implemented in that way:

```
class Hello(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        if name == '':
            return self
        return Resource.getChild(self, name, request)$
```

As far as I understand, there is a recursive call to the getChild method
but who (which method in which class ?) is in charge of removing path
segments from name ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

For example, the URL /foo/bar/baz will normally be:

```
Resource.getChild('foo').getChild('bar').getChild('baz')
```

However, if the resource returned by 'bar' has isLeaf set to true, then the getChild call will never be made on it.

Comment: Thanks, coppettim ... but what I do not understand in the code is how can this work as no segment path is removed from "name" ...

Answer (score 2):

the caller for getChild(self, name, request) can be obtained using the inspect module.

```
import inspect
...
class Hello(Resource):
    #isLeaf = True  # This has to be left out, to ensure, getChild is called!
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        print inspect.stack()[2][1]
        return self
```

Now you will see the output in the stdout saying:

```
2012-09-17 11:16:24+0200 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] getChildForRequest
```

If you take a look at the API documentation in the section [web/resource/Resource](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py) and look at the source of Resource, you can find the method "[getChildForRequest](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py#L172)" (line 172), and find a deprecation warning, which says "...use module level getChildForRequest.", which means look at the module level to find that [function (line 58)](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py#L58).

And here we go, that module level function does the funny thing with traversing the path elements by checking for "isLeaf" and moving prepath and postpath elements. If our resource has "isLeaf", the resource is returned, otherwise if request.postpath exists and "isLeaf" is false, the paths will be moved around and [resource.getChildWithDefault](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py#L155) is called, which itself looks for an always available resource (added with putChild or simply existant in self.children dict) and if it cannot find one, it calls "[getChild](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py#L129)" which should return a dynamic resource, or it ends up with the default return of getChild, which is: [NoResource("No such child resource") in Line 152](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py#L152).

Cheers
Laidback